# How to properly lock a Task.Run() block

Tags: c#, locking, task

I am writing an application where I use several methods that access to some shared resources, so implemented some safety via `lock(thisLock){ [...] ]`

All was well until I had to use a resources inside an async task.
This is the code:

```
private object thisLock = new object();
[...]
private void UpdateStuff()
{
lock(thisLock)
   {
     Task.Run(()=>{[code where I use shared resources]});
   }
}
```

It seems to work fine, but I was wondering if this is the correct way to do, or if I should put the `lock()` part inside the Run(), like this:

```
private void UpdateStuff()
{

     Task.Run( () => {
        lock(thisLock)
        {
         [code where I use shared resources]
        }
     });    
}
```

I tried to get some information, but everything I found mentions the case when the keyword `async`is used, and this doesn't seems the case.

So, my question is: which one is the best/correct way to use a lock() with Task.Run()? Why?

Thank you!

EDIT: In order to clarify, my doubt is about when and how much the lock is effective, so basically I am asking if in the first case there is a possibility where the lock is valid just for the `Run()` call, since the content of the call itself could live in another thread, while in the second case the lock will be associated to the content and so be effective.

Comment: Can locking be avoided? E.g. instead of having mutable data, `Task` might return a result, which could be used in continuation, then you don't need to lock mutable data.

Comment: Not really, as I would like to reserve resources used inside the task code, not the output of the task itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your first approach is entirely wrong. `Task.Run` can either execute the work synchronously on the same thread **or queue it to a thread pool.** You don't know which is going to happen.

You aren't waiting for the task to complete, so if it gets queued to a thread pool, your function is going to release the lock and return, potentially before the work has even started.

In general, best practice is to only acquire locks for as little time as needed, and never keep a lock held while waiting for another thread, as you can end up with a deadlock very easily if you aren't extremely careful.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly,  the second approach is the most correct one, as in the first one the lock would be valid only for the `Run()` call, but not for the entire `{ [code where I use shared resources] }` part, right?

Comment: Yes, it may sometimes only acquire the lock for `Run()` and not the code in the task.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a best way between these two, you just obtain 2 different results:

In the first case, you won't start a task till the lock is opened.

In the second case you will start a task which won't do anything till the lock is opened.

In my opinion not opening a task till you need it, is a better approach, but it's just a personal opinion. Opening and locking after, will allocate useless resources.

Comment: My concern comes from this: if I undestand correctly, in the first case the lock would reserve only the run call, and since it is async wouldn't the lock be opened immediately after, nullifying its effect? In the second case instead, the lock is included in the task, so everything should be properly reserved, right?

Comment: if the class is sync or async this code will work in the exactly same way

Comment: Maybe I don't get your question